# How do I get source code from a webpage that is already open on my pc (chrome) with python

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

My goal is to read html from a website. The problem is this website is blocked when opened by a guest browser like selenium does. So I need to manually open this webpage so I can read the html. So how do I get selenium(or any other library) to read the html from a browser I have opened myself ?

Comment: Save the source as a file and open it in Python?

Comment: No web browser has the ability to "block" a web site.  If it did, the internet would not work at all.  You can get the HTML code for any site simply by opening the page in any standard browser and selecting "View page source."  On Chrome it's in the right click popup menu.

Comment: Its not necessarily that its blocked but It wont show the content of the page unless the correct header is passed. I can pass the correct header by using a browser extension. The problem is selenium opens a guest browser that does not have this extension.

Comment: I think there is a python library for web scraping called beautiful soup. Have a look if that's the right thing for your purpose.

Comment: Yes but I don’t think this library allows you to access a browser that is already opened